# What is the difference between a AC-DC power supply and a AC-DC switching power supply

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc

I need a power supply for 200W 48vdc brushed motor. It will run at 2300 rpm and need 5 amps to generate 150 in-lbs torque. Will both AC-DC and AC-DC switching power supplies work. If both will work is one preferable?

Thanks,
henrylr

Comment: We can't really answer that as not all power supplies are created equal. You would need to specify each power supply so the specifications could be found.

Comment: it is like the difference between an `apple` and a `yellow apple`

Answer (score 2):

- A power supply is a device that supplies power
- Usually (not always) the output voltage of a power supply is lower than the input voltage (for example: input = 240 V, output is 48 V)
- Usually a power supply converts AC into low voltage DC (for example: input = 240 V AC, output is 48 V DC)
- **Some** power supplies a are a "switching power supply", that means electronics are used to convert the power using high frequency (for example, 100 kHz) **switching**. This results in a more efficient and cheaper power supply.
- The alternative to the "switching" power supply is the "linear power supply" which uses a low frequency transformer (50 or 60 Hz mains AC) and a "linear regulator" (can be a switching regulator as well though). These supplies are **heavy** due to the large low frequency transformer and expensive (more material is needed).
- If you buy a new 200 W, 48 V AC to DC power supply today then this will be a **switching** supply. Non-switching supplies do exist but you will pay more and for powering a motor, a switching supply is perfectly fine.

Do realize that connecting the motor **directly** to the power supply might not work, the motor might draw a very high current when starting up. Generally a **motor controller** is used between power supply and motor.

Your 5 A motor is also too much for a 200 W, 48 V supply. A 200 W, 48 V supply can only deliver 200 W / 48 V = 4.17 A which is less than 5 A. You might need at least a 250 W supply.

It is good practice to use an even higher rated supply so for example 300 W, 48 V. Such a supply can "easily" deliver 5 A (while a 250 W supply would be struggeling).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The motor max continuous torque is 150 oz-in and oz-in/AMPS = 28.13. I want to run it at about 140 oz-in so that will require approx. 5 amps. Should the power supply spec. not be over 5 amps?

Comment: Thanks again. Obviously I know very little about DC motors and power supplies. So would a power supply rated 6 or 10 amps drive the motor beyond the max torque rating.

Comment: I've been breaking it in with a 19 VDC 3.42AMP 65W wall wart and it starts and runs well. Would that indicate I don't need a motor controller?

Comment: *Should the power supply spec. not be over 5 amps?* Re-read what I wrote about the current for the power supply. *I've been breaking it in with a 19 VDC 3.42AMP 65W wall wart and it starts and runs well.* That doesn't mean anything. It is still possible that you're overloading that 19 V supply and it might get damaged or worse, burst in flames, if you do this for a longer period.

Comment: I re-read it but don't understand what will keep the motor from exceeding the max torque of 150 oz-in which = 5.33 amps.